# No route matches {:action => "show" ...} while params[:action] returns "edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

just like in title, i have weird problem going into `edit` action in controller. when i try to get, error is

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /pages/header/foo/edit
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages", :menu=>#<Page id: 1, title: "tytul", slug: "foo", name: "kupa", position: 1, created_at: "2013-08-27 12:46:26", updated_at: "2013-08-30 07:57:58", menu: "header">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

i think it might be connected to my `routes.rb` file which uses path to define resources:

```
resources :pages, path: "pages/:menu"
```

and so, when i type eg `www.example.dev/pages/forum/interesting_topic` i get proper response, action `show` with `@page = interesting_topic (and :menu = "forum")`.
but on the other hand `www.example.dev/pages/forum/interesting_topic/edit` brings me to the error above. which is really strange, since my params look like this:

```
{"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"pages", "menu"=>"forum", "id"=>"interesting_topic"}
```

How is that possible that i have correct params, with correct action `edit`, and still get error that talks about action `show`...?
(maybe worth mentioning is that `better-errors` last application page, is what i need, meaning form, making it even more weird)

EDIT
rake routes

```
sort_pages GET    /pages/:menu/sort(.:format)                 pages#sort
    save_order_pages POST   /pages/:menu/save_order(.:format)           pages#save_order
               pages GET    /pages/:menu(.:format)                      pages#index
                     POST   /pages/:menu(.:format)                      pages#create
            new_page GET    /pages/:menu/new(.:format)                  pages#new
           edit_page GET    /pages/:menu/:id/edit(.:format)             pages#edit
                page GET    /pages/:menu/:id(.:format)                  pages#show
                     PATCH  /pages/:menu/:id(.:format)                  pages#update
                     PUT    /pages/:menu/:id(.:format)                  pages#update
                     DELETE /pages/:menu/:id(.:format)                  pages#destroy
```

2nd. EDIT

since i deleted everything from the partial rendered by 'edit' view and it suddenly started to work, im giving it here, with edit action

```
= simple_form_for @page do |f|
  .inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :slug
    = f.input :name
  .actions
    =f.button :submit
```

And controller

```
before_filter :set_page, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def edit
end

 private

  def set_page
    @page = Page.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: please put your `rake routes` output

Answer (score 0):

Check the server logs in your terminal window - you likely have an invalid link to a show page, in your edit view.

edit: Oh I see, it's a routing issue. Because you have an extra variable in your routing (`:menu` as well as `:id`) you need to provide that extra variable when defining your form.

Try the following (if menu is supposed to equal 'forum')

```
= simple_form_for :forum, @page do |f|
```

(leave the rest the same)

Comment: and what is in this form partial?

Comment: and in form, just simple_form, no links, no nothing

Comment: just updated my question, also, i'm looking into the log right now, but i see nothing helpful:(

Comment: 'can't write unknown attribute `builder'' is my error now. plus 'new'&'create' action worked like a charm before, even though edit was broken

Comment: maybe not then. It's definitely related to not providing the `menu` variable for your route.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36547/discussion-between-kuba-polaczek-and-sevenseacat)

Answer (score 0):

changing simple_form form into this worked for me:

```
= simple_form_for @page, url: @page.new_record? ? pages_path(params[:menu]) : page_path(params[:menu], @page)
```